# Authenticating external user using Azure AD

Tags: azure-ad

Environment: Sitecore version 9.0

I have successfully integrated Azure AD for our Sitecore client application.

However, for some reason, now I would like to authenticate my website user (external user) from the same Azure AD using custom button on different login page.

I have tried using `GetSignInUrlInfoPipeline`but after successful authentication from Azure AD end, application didn't get the user information.

Also , when I check the Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated`, I am getting the value false.

Any clue?

Comment: which Sitecore version are you using , can you give log info ?

Comment: Are you able to provide any of your code or configuration to allow people to look for issues?